# Azure Data Factory pipeline - if fails on inner activity

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have developed an Azure Data Factory pipeline that checks the schema of files in the data lake. I have 15 files in the "templates format" and I check them against files received from customers. I have both xlsx and CSV files.

[image]

First I take all file names from the template folder and iterate them. I need to check if the current file is excel, as when I need to define whether a file is an xlsx or CSV.

[image]

I want to handle both types of issues. First when a schema of the received file is different from the schema of the template. And second when I have not received this file at all. So in the Set Variable activity, I use this code. So I can use it in switch activity.

```
@concat('Excel',
if(equals(activity('Get Metadata of excel bronze').Status,'Succeeded'),' True' , ' False'),
if(equals(activity('Get Metadata of excel bronze').Status,activity('Get Metadata of excel 
template').Status),' True' , ' False')
)
```

[image]

However, when I have not received a file and I have a template "Get a metadata of excel" the template fails and the whole "Is Excel" activity fails. Is there a possibility to force if the activity to not fail on error? An error is expected in this pipeline.

[image]

Comment: Really need more information on the first step.... Get Metadata. Will you sometimes find no files? Or files that don't meet your criteria? If no files are found then it shouldn't iterate in the For Each, but it sounds like you are getting all the files in a directory, if the file is excel then do A, otherwise do B, but you are having issues where the file is neither an excel or csv? If the files you consume should only be excel or CSV then you can do a filter activity prior to the for each to filter to just excel or CSV files. That should help you there

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new activity upon failure so that even `Get Metadata` fails, pipeline keeps running the next steps.

[image]

**Note**: When you are connecting 2 different activity outputs to a new activity (set variable activity) as input, the `Set Variable` activity only runs when both inputs are successful and fails to run if any one of the input activities is failed.

[image]

The workaround is to connect the Get Metadata outputs to 2 different activities.

For each `Get Metadata` activity, add set variable activity (or any other required activity) on success and failure individually to run the pipeline without stopping when error occur.

[image]

Pipeline runs even when Get Metadata2 fails when connected to other activity upon failure.

[image]